# Find the area of the given triangle

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Another mathematical puzzle:

> Find the area of $\triangle FGH$, given that $FG=FH$ and the radii of the circles shown are $2$ and $1$
>
> [image: Made with GeoGebra]

Comment: please provide the source if this is not your own work. else it will likely be closed. thanks

Comment: The question says FG=GH but the diagram is drawn as if FG=FH and GH is very different. Is there a typo in the question, or is the diagram deliberately very misleading?

Comment: It somewhat looks like a homework...

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1766545/369453 :D

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thanks for pointing that out, I've fixed it. Also, good catch by Marius! I didn't know that this had been asked before. It's purely coincidential :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> $16\sqrt2$

Because:

> if you draw radii where the circles are tangent to the triangles with tangent points marked as $D$ (smaller circle) and $E$ (larger circle; this forms right angles), you get the following similar triangles: $\triangle FDA \sim \triangle FEB \sim \triangle FXG$. $A$ is the center of the small circle and $B$ is the center of the large one. $X$ is the midpoint of $HG$.

From this, we get this proportion:

> $\frac{FA}{FB} = \frac{DA}{EB}$ OR $\frac{FA}{FA+3} = \frac{1}{2}$ because of the radii lengths.

So:

> $FA=3$

Using Pythagorean Theorem:

> $FD = \sqrt8$

Using our similar triangle relations from the beginning, we get:

> $XG = 2\sqrt2$

Finally, we use the area of a triangle formula to get:

> $16\sqrt2$

Comment: Sorry, I got tired of showing my work...

Comment: I'm sure this is a good answer, but I got kind of lost when you started drawing new things. If you had a picture, that would help greatly.

Comment: @Chipster - No, you're right... I'll add that in when I find time!

Comment: A picture would help, but even with no picture, please could you clarify which point is $D$ and which is $E$?

Comment: @RosieF -- $D$ is for the smaller circle and $E$ is for the larger one.

Answer (score 2):

Let $h$ denote the height of the triangle from F onto GH. Then, by Pythagoras' theorem, $$FG^2=h^2+(GH/2)^2,$$ and by triangles' similarity $$h:(GH/2) = (FG-GH/2):2$$ and $$(h-4):h = 1:2.$$

[image: similar triangles]

Can you continue from this?

From the last we get $h-4=h/2$ which resolves to $h=8.$ Plug it to previous two to get

> $$\begin{cases}FG^2=64+(GH/2)^2\\8:(GH/2) = (FG-GH/2):2\end{cases}$$
>  The last equation is equivalent to
>  $$16:(GH/2) = (FG-GH/2)$$

hence

> $$FG = (GH/2)+16:(GH/2)$$
>  and
>  $$FG^2 = (GH/2)^2 + 32 + 256:(GH/2)^2$$

> Compare it to the first equation:
>  $$64+(GH/2)^2 = (GH/2)^2 + 32 + 256:(GH/2)^2$$
>  $$64 = 32 + 256:(GH/2)^2$$
>  $$32 = 256:(GH/2)^2$$
>  $$(GH/2)^2 = 256:32 = 8$$
>  $$GH/2 = \sqrt 8 = 2\sqrt 2$$

Finally the area sought is

> $$S_{\triangle FGH} = h\cdot GH/2 = 16\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: See my answer; I think I got it??

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Yes, you did. I didn't show my solution at first, because the question looks like a homework (my [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101074/find-the-area-of-the-given-triangle/101078#comment287339_101074)), so I wanted the author to show some effort first. Now I uncommented the hiden part with the same result as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Let me chip in with a streamlined answer.

> $8\sqrt 8$

> All the smaller circle is telling us is that the height of the triangle must be $8$, so let's jot that down and from here pretend the small circle never existed.

> The points where the circle (there is only one circle!) touches the triangle divide the long sides into two segments of lengths $y>x$ and the base into two equal segments of length $x$. Let us now compute the area $A$ of the triangle from base and height $A=8x$, from incircle radius and circumference $A=2(2x+y)$ and from Heron's formula $A^2=x^2y(2x+y)$. Comparing the first two gives $2x=y$, together with the last we get $x=\sqrt 8$ and $A=8\sqrt 8$.

Comment: Please explain where A = 2(2x + y) came from. Thanks.

Comment: @asg as it says _"from incircle radius and circumference"_. $2x+y$ is the semicircumference often written $s$ of the triangle.